# Writing XFCE panel plugins in Python?

Tags: python, xfce

I've Googled around a bit, but can't find much. [This](http://pyxfce.xfce.org/) seems rather out of date, and doesn't provide any examples. Is this possible? Should I just shut up and learn C already?

Comment: By the way, the link is broken posted by @KenKinder